# Make Javascript code smaller and more optimized

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, minify

I am trying to optimize the code below to be as small as possible (because a client is supposed to just paste it into their website code).
Is it possible to minimize it further (i am using minify to compress spaces and stuff but is there any coding i can do to make it smaller?).

```
<span id="gmbdata"></span>

<script>
function specHours() {
  var x = document.getElementById("spec");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function myFunc(myObj) {

var dag="";var gmbdata="";
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) 
{
    dag="day"+i;timme="hours"+i;
    gmbdata += '<span style="width:15ch;display:inline-block;">'+myObj[dag]+'</span><span style="padding-left:5px;">'+myObj[timme]+'</span><br />';
}
 document.getElementById("gmbdata").innerHTML = gmbdata;
  if(myObj.specialopeninghours != "") document.getElementById("specialopeninghours").innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="specHours()">Speciella öpettider</a><div id="spec" style="display:none"><span>'+myObj.specialopeninghours+'</span></div>';
}
</script>

<script src="https://XXX"></script>
```

Comment: Just use any of the many available minifiers?

Comment: The `if` condition is a very simple 1-line ternary for starters. you only use `day` and `timme` once so not much point exlicitly declaring them. There's _loads_ of ways this code could be shorter

Comment: @Jamiec and almost none that I can think of should be done by hand. We've had tools for this for many, many years.

Comment: @VLAZ yes indeed!

Comment: This is turning into a talk show. like Operah on TV. go on though. am enjoying it...

Answer (score -2):

You could change the condition in the first function into a ternary as below

```
function specHours() {
  var x = document.getElementById("spec");
  x.style.display  = x.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

am not sure where this function is used. am not seeing it used anywhere else but here is another way.

```
function specHours() {
  var x = document.getElementById("spec");
  "none" === x.style.display ? x.style.display = "block" : x.style.display = "none"
}
```

I have not tested this but theoretically it should work just fine.

Ideally, the first looks shorter. :)

The second function could be reduced to;

```
function myFunc(myObj) {
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) 
{
    gmbdata += '<span style="width:15ch;display:inline-block;">'+myObj["day"+i]+'</span><span style="padding-left:5px;">'+myObj["hours"+i]+'</span><br />';
}
 document.getElementById("gmbdata").innerHTML = gmbdata;
  if(myObj.specialopeninghours != "") document.getElementById("specialopeninghours").innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="specHours()">Speciella öpettider</a><div id="spec" style="display:none"><span>'+myObj.specialopeninghours+'</span></div>';
}
```

The declaration of Day and Time is not necessary.

after this, what you could do more is to use shorter names/declarations/variables/whatever-it-is-called.
eg:

```
function myFunc(myObj) {
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) 
{
    gd += '<span style="width:15ch;display:inline-block;">'+myObj["day"+i]+'</span><span style="padding-left:5px;">'+myObj["hours"+i]+'</span><br />';
}
 document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = g;
  if(myObj.s != "") document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="specHours()">Speciella öpettider</a><div id="spec" style="display:none"><span>'+myObj.s+'</span></div>';
}
```

Comment: And may I know why I have been marked down?

Comment: `x = x === "none" ? "block" : "none";` does not do the same thing. It just assigns the variable `x` it does not change `.style.display`

Comment: true. let's fix it quick. Thanks

Comment: `none" === x.style.display ? x.style.display = "block" : x.style.display = "none"` is longer than `x.style.display  = x.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";` because now `x.style.display` is repeated three times instead of two and there are two assignments instead of one....

Comment: Exactly what the minifier would likely produce if it was used. I jus thought I share options.

Comment: "*<some code> you could further reduced it to <longer code>*"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231503/discussion-between-mw509-and-vlaz).

Comment: No need to. I pointed out your current message makes a factually incorrect statement. "further reduced" means it should be *shorter*. It's not. No need for a discussion.

Comment: right. got it. :facepalm